# Can we get a helper link in the nav bar that shows us our unmarked/unanswered questions?

Tags: feature-request

Oftentimes, I find that I have let a lot of my questions go unanswered, so I like to go back and mark answers.  It's sort of tedious to have to type in `user:me hasaccepted:0` in the search bar every time I want to do this, especially since I am a member of several StackExchange sites.

If there were a link in the main nav bar that would take me to `http://whateverstacksite.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3A0` then that would be awesome.  Right now, I have favorites pointing to search results for the StackExchange site I want to search unanswered questions for, but it'd be nice to be able to get rid of that.

Comment: Every time someone does something on your question, you get a notice in your inbox - be this a comment or answer.  If your question doesn't have enough attention, you could place a bounty on it instead after 2 days.

Comment: I know that.  This has nothing to do with trying to get answers.  It's about looking through all the questions you've asked that have answers, none of which you've yet marked.  Haven't you ever looked at your answer ratio and decided to go back and see if you have any questions that you can legitimately mark with someone's answer?

Comment: I've only ever asked one question before on SO (and three on Meta), but looking through the Questions tab in my profile seems to be *the* feature you're requesting.  I'm not sure I see the benefit in introducing more redundancy.

Comment: Hey, good call.  I never saw that.  Still, you have to flip through several pages of questions.  With the helper link, it would filter it down to unanswered only.  Maybe I am being too needy now.  I wouldn't have asked this had I known about that page you mentioned.